# Relational operators on multiple decimal "numbers"

Tags: powershell

I have a need to compare build numbers with a multiple decimal format, and I am wondering if there is either a PowerShell native or .NET way to do this, rather than rolling my own.
I started with a simple -gt and strings, like this

```
if ('12.3.0' -gt '12.2.3') {
   $true
} else {
   $false
}
```

And it works, but only as long as the number of digits matches. So this falls apart.

```
if ('12.10.0' -gt '12.2.3') {
   $true
} else {
   $false
}
```

To make matters worse, some vendors like Autodesk will use letters in their build, um, numbers. So you get builds like N.44.0 and O.12.0 (that's a capital O there in front). Which gets really iffy.
I'm sure I could roll my own and Split each build number on the decimal and than establish and cast to the correct type of each "digit" and do a compare then. But that's a fair amount of work to do if PS has a built in solution I just haven't found yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version strings vary in format and content from software publisher to software publisher, and possibly even product to product. You'll have to "roll your own", and it'll end up being different for each vendor/product.

*Edited to add:* Per @Bill_Stewart, the `[Version]` .NET class can possibly simplify some of the issues involved. See the [MSDN description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I figured that might be the answer. At this point I already have a shorthand nomenclature for the different Autodesk products, which are the main problem children for me. I guess I'll gather all that info and roll me a compare function over the weekend. Thanks for the verification!

Comment: This kind of problem surfaces very often when you try to integrate data that was concocted in a non integrated fashion.

Comment: The `[Version]` class can be pretty helpful here...`([Version] "1.3") -gt ([Version] "1.0.3")` is `$true`.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart - That's obscure! Thanks for mentioning it. The potential problem with it is the case where any of the components is non-numeric. Like the AutoDesk numbers in the question. For those, definitely, he'll still have to roll his own, and if any of the parts of an all-numeric version string exceed an int32, ditto. `[Version]` may well make rolling his own easier, but it's going to be far from a panacea.

Comment: Yeah, [Version] is certainly going to be a big help. If I get lucky the only Autodesk product that is non standard is AutoCAD, which has been using the same lame approach for like 20 years now. I may even be bale to convert the alphabetic into a character number and use [Version] still.